# Subtract 1 from the first item in the Q2 array, 2 from the second item, 3 from the third item..n for the nth item and call it Q3

Tags: python, numpy

i'm working on a school assignment. I have an array called Q2 and it wants me to create Q3 by subtracting . The actual array is much longer but this is the first few values:

```
Q2 = [341, 50178, 356)
```

my advised creating a second array that can be used in combination with the first and that we may want to use the linspace() method. She also suggested not using a for loop

the output should be:

```
array([340, 50176, 353)
```

I'm really stuck and not sure how to proceed. I read about the linspace method but i don't understand how that could result in a decrease in values. I tried using the subtract method but it says it's in the wrong shape. Does anyone have any guidance?

Comment: Please do not ask Stack Overflow to do your homework. You will not learn anything that way.  What have you tried?

Comment: So i tried to look at the discussion boards and the TA suggested finding the length of Q2 (which is 812160) so i created an array that was QA = (1,812160) and then i tried to do the subtract method to subtract Q2-QA but i get an error that the shape is off, then i tried to do linspace(1, 81260, -1) but i can't do negative numbers and after reading about linspace i dont understand how that could get me the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.linspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) to generate an array to subtract from `Q2`, by passing it parameters:

- *start*: 1
- *stop*: Q2.size
- *num*: Q2.size

Then you can assign `Q3` from the subtraction of that from `Q2`:

```py
Q2 = np.array([341, 50178, 356])
sub = np.linspace(1, Q2.size, Q2.size)
# array([1., 2., 3.])
Q3 = Q2 - sub
# array([  340., 50176.,   353.])
```

Note that for this particular use case, using [`np.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) (as described in @mozway answer) instead of `linspace` would be more efficient.

Comment: I was using linspace wrong. This made it much more clear and worked, thank you so much!!

Comment: Isn't `linspace` inappropriate here? This might be less efficient to compute, prone to rounding errors, and forces an upcasting to float.

Comment: @mozway OP says they were suggested to use it... I would agree that for this specific case `arange` is better suited.

Comment: @mozway I've added a note to that effect.

Comment: @xxlpb you should ask your instructor about this choice, seems like a bad use case to me (don't follow instructions blindly, use your criticism) ;)

Comment: @mozway just realised I forgot to attribute the arange in my comment. Sorry about that, fixed now.

Comment: @Nick no worries and no need to ;)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your want to remove `[1, 2, 3]`, in which case [`arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) should be used (not [`linspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html)):

```
Q2 = np.array([341, 50178, 356])
Q3 = Q2-np.arange(1, Q2.shape[0]+1)
```

Output:

```
array([  340, 50176,   353])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply subtract every index value from that particular entry and won't even require a new array. Here is the code

import numpy as np

#Let's say you have a sample array

arr = np.array(1,2,3)

for x in arr:
arr[x]-=x

Comment: Please put your code in a code block